# TypeScript readonly ( Error : Duplicate identifier 'readonly') ReferenceError: x is not defined

Tags: typescript

I was testing `readonly` following the [basarat](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/readonly.html#readonly) book. I have this error on IDE:

> Duplicate identifier 'readonly'. (property) Foo.readonly: number

```
class Foo {

    readonly bar = 1;
    readonly baz: string;

    constructor() {
        this.baz = "hello";
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I get:

```
this.readonly = baz;
                ^
ReferenceError: baz is not defined
```

Something changed in typescript? I have to set something in the `tsconfig.json` to make use of this, I tried ES5 and ES6 and nothing changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readonly` keyword as described on this [TypeScript GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12) is scheduled for the 2.0 milestone.

You will need to use version 2.0 or above for this feature to be available for instance and static members.